# Xamarin Android System.ObjectDisposedException when scrolling through ListView of Images

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am writing an Android app using Xamarin.Forms, and I've been seeing this ***System.ObjectDisposedException:** 'Cannot access a closed Stream.'* come up on one of my pages where I have a ListView with Images in it.  When scrolling down, the images load fine and all is well.  But when scrolling back up, that exception is thrown.  The images come from a database as a byte[], so I am using Memory Streams to assign the Image sources. The exception is coming from the streams closing, but I am not sure how to keep them open or find some other workaround for this issue.

Here is my xaml:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding imageGallery}" x:Name="imageList" RowHeight="100" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid >
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Image Source="{Binding photo.Source}" x:Name="imageInGrid" Rotation="90" Grid.Column="0" MinimumHeightRequest="100" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Center" >
                                    <Label Text="{Binding date}" FontSize="18" TextColor="Navy" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding manifestNum}" FontSize="18" TextColor="Navy" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Here is my C#:

```
static ObservableCollection<ImageViewer> imageGallery;
static List<Stream> streams;
        public ImagesPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            imageGallery = new ObservableCollection<ImageViewer>();
            streams = new List<Stream>();

            //query string
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(queryString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            ImageViewer viewer = new ImageViewer
                            {
                                imageData = (byte[]) reader[2],
                                photo = new Image(),
                                date = reader[1].ToString().Split(' ')[0],
                                manifestNum = reader[0].ToString().Substring(4)
                            };
                            Stream stream = new MemoryStream(viewer.imageData);
                            viewer.photo.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => { return stream; });
                            streams.Add(stream);
                            imageGallery.Add(viewer);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            imageList.ItemsSource = imageGallery;
        }
```

Comment: Store the streams in a `List<Stream>` field of the class you are in (ImagesPage?). Then they will exist, as long as that class (page) exists.

Comment: I tried this and I still got the same exception.  Also, yes, the name of the class is Images Page

Comment: *"I tried this and I still got the same exception.*" When you make a change to code that you've shown in question, it is important to **show** in the question what the code looks like now. Otherwise, it is impossible to know what you did exactly, so it is impossible to help you figure out why it still doesn't work.

Comment: To clarify, I added in an instance variable of type List<Stream> and added the streams when they were created, but the same exception still resulted

Comment: I don't see an edit to the code in the question. Sorry, I'm not going to read your description in comment above, and assume I've correctly inferred exactly what code you are running now. If you want someone to help figure out what is wrong with your code, show the exact code.